# Removing lines from csv fileInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My `Shiny` program has the users upload their specific `.csv` file through `fileInput`; however, currently it currently requires some minor editing before upload. The program which stores the data has an export CSV feature, but the `.csv` file it creates has a couple summary statistic lines which export poorly. Hence, when the user uploads as-is it generates the error:

```
Warning: Error in sum: invalid 'type' (character) of argument
  [No stack trace available]
```

A short example of what the `.csv` file exported:

```
Rep,Sales,Profits
A,"10000","5000"
B,"8000","4000"
,"Sum:18000","Sum:9000"
,"Avg:9000","Avg:4500"
```

It will properly treat the first line as the header, but since `Sum:18000` etc. are just character type, they cause the error. Currently, the user is required to manually delete these lines before upload, but I was hoping to integrate automatic file editing into `Shiny`.

Without any file editing integrate, my server handling of the user `fileInput`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

     abcInput <- reactive({req(input$rdata)
          tibble(read_csv(input$rdata$datapath))})


     abcSum <- reactive({sum(abcInput()$`Profit`)})
     abcCount <- reactive({nrow(abcInput())})

}
```

My thought process was to use `system()` from `R` and pass through commands to `zsh`. So I pondered something like:

```
sed -i '' '$d' file.csv
```

Repeated multiple times or through pipes, ugly I know, but works (macOS). Is there a way to achieve this via `system()` before initiating `read_csv()` and `tibble()`? Or perhaps another method of removing the last few lines of the user uploaded file?

Comment: Also in case anyone gets concerned, the files will be the exact same set-up every time they are uploaded. It is a pretty linear process and I coordinate with them exactly how to use it. So there isn't any concern on my part of possible data loss from editing their files in the background. Just trying to save time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to remove the lines with the summary stats after importing and to convert your data to numerics inside the app? Also note that you don't have to wrap `read_csv` in `tibble` as ´read_csv` will return a `tibble`by default.

Comment: @stefan Good point on the `read_csv`; however, I am confused on your first part. How would you suggest handling removing the lines? Upon import how can I trim off those lines?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment one option would be to do the data cleaning inside the app. The following code provides a minimal reprex of how I would approach this task where I uncommented or dropped all code related to reading the file via `fileInput`:

```r
csv <- 'Rep,Sales,Profits
A,"10000","5000"
B,"8000","4000"
,"Sum:18000","Sum:9000"
,"Avg:9000","Avg:4500"'


library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  #fileInput("rdata", "Upload a file"),
  tableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("sum"),
  verbatimTextOutput("count")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  abcInput <- reactive({
    #req(input$rdata)
    #raw read_csv(input$rdata$datapath)
    raw <- read.table(text = csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    raw |> 
      filter(!is.na(Rep), !Rep=="") |> 
      mutate(across(c(Sales, Profits), as.numeric))
  })
  
  abcSum <- reactive({
    sum(abcInput()$`Profit`)
  })
  abcCount <- reactive({
    nrow(abcInput())
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    abcInput()  
  })
  output$sum <- renderText({
    abcSum()  
  })
  output$count <- renderText({
    abcCount()  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8550
```

[image]

Comment: `fileInput` is rather integral to the purpose of this app as it is the user's own dataset. This appears to instead hardcode the example dataset I gave rather than accept any input and clean that input. I did find a solution with some help from your assistance though and will post it on here. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah. I just uncommented the `fileInput` for the reprex to focus on the data cleaning. It's hard to make a reprex where one has to upload a file from a local drive. (; This will of course also work with `fileInput` as long as the files have the same structure as the example data you provided.

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes sense. I reread your answer after this and now I follow along, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a decent solution that could probably get cleaned up, but appears to be functional for my purpose.

```
     abcInput <- reactive({req(input$rdata)
          read_csv(input$rdata$datapath) %>%
             filter(row_number() %in% 
                (1:nrow(read_csv(input$rdata$datapath))-2)) %>%
             mutate(across(c(Sales, Profits), readr::parse_number))
     })
```

With `filter` serving as the means for removing the last couple lines of the csv and then leveraging `readr::parse_number` to coerce the numeric columns which include commas.